# How do I make npm or yarn install a specific version of a specific sub-package from github?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, yarnpkg, lerna

I have a [repo](https://github.com/rtsao/styletron) that I forked from a project on github with a structure like so:

```
myfork.git
  |
  -- packages
        |
        --subpackage1
              |
              --package.json
        |
        --subpackage2
              |
              --package.json
```

I made some minor modifications to subpackage1 in a separate branch foo. Now I want to use it in a project. So I tried the following

```
yarn add https://github.com/myuser/myfork.git/subpackage1#foo
yarn add https://github.com/myuser/myfork.git/packages/subpackage1#foo
```

Then I tried without the branch specifier. Then I tried `npm install` instead of `yarn add`. Then I tried to just install without anything other than the base url which fails because there's no version number in the top-level `package.json`. I am clearly missing something here but I cannot figure out what.